# How to create Html->link for plugins

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakedc Users plugin https://github.com/CakeDC/users which is very good for me

But I have a problem that the default layout for this plugin is located in `APP_ROOT\vendor\cakedc\users\src\Template\Layout`

But the default layout for my app is located in `APP_ROOT\src\Template\Layout`

I didn't think this was a big problem I just copied the default layout from my src folder to the plugin folder , But my problem is the links that they were pointing to my website

`EXAMPLE.COM/FAQ` converted to `EXAMPLE.COM/USERS/FAQ`

I am using `<?= $this->Html->link(__('FAQ'), ['controller'=>'faqs']) ?>` to create the links

So how can I fix this problem ?

---

Small update : I just thought of using the old ../ hack and it worked

`<?= $this->Html->link(__('FAQ'), ['controller'=>'../faqs']) ?>` Gived me the  result that I want , But I still want another solution if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plugin view templates should be overwritten via application templates

You're not supposed to fiddle in the plugin source code, your changes are going to be lost with the next update!

Check the plugin and CakePHP docs on how to properly overwrite plugin view templates.

> [...]
>
> You can override any plugin views from inside your app using special paths. If you have a plugin called `ContactManager` you can override the template files of the plugin with application specific view logic by creating files using the following template `src/Template/Plugin/[Plugin]/[Controller]/[view].ctp`. For the Contacts controller you could make the following file:
>
> ```
> src/Template/Plugin/ContactManager/Contacts/index.ctp
> ```
>
> [...]

- **https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.1.4/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md#updating-the-templates**
- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Overriding Plugin Templates from Inside Your Application](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application)**

Layouts can be overwritten in the same manner by using paths like

```
src/Template/Plugin/[Plugin]/Layout/[layout].ctp
```

So for the `cakedc/users` plugin the default layout could be overwritten via

```
src/Template/Plugin/Users/Layout/default.ctp
```

### Break out of plugin scopes via the `plugin` option

If you need code that is evaluated in a plugin scope to generate non-plugin URLs, use the `plugin` option to break out by passing `false` or `null`.

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('FAQ'), ['controller' => 'faqs', 'plugin' => false]) ?>
```